# Combining multiple lines in Perl

Tags: perl

Can someone help me out?

Here's my record:

```
Client1|fiswt|36214|784423|21 March 2013
Office|Level 9 83 Clarence Street
Transout|Cash|6904.29|$2.32|$16,000.00
closingtot|$236,313.84

Client1|fiswt|36214|784423|21 March 2013
Office|Level 9 83 Clarence Street
Transout|Cash|6904.29|$2.32|$16,000.00
closingtot|$236,313.84

Client1|fiswt|36214|784423|21 March 2013
Office|Level 9 83 Clarence Street
Transout|Cash|6904.29|$2.32|$16,000.00
closingtot|$236,313.84
```

Here's the sample output that I wanted to have.

```
Client1|fiswt|36214|784423|21 March 2013|Office|Level 9 83 Clarence Street|Transout|Cash|6904.29|$2.32|$16,000.00|closingtot|$236,313.84
Client1|fiswt|36214|784423|21 March 2013|Office|Level 9 83 Clarence Street|Transout|Cash|6904.29|$2.32|$16,000.00|closingtot|$236,313.84
Client1|fiswt|36214|784423|21 March 2013|Office|Level 9 83 Clarence Street|Transout|Cash|6904.29|$2.32|$16,000.00|closingtot|$236,313.84
```

I actually have this Solution:

```
chomp($line) unless($line =~ /^Closing/i);
```

but the there is some problem with the output at the end of each line a pipe(|) should be added:

like this

$16,000.00|closingtot|$236,313.84

Comment: I think you can use readline and . to combine the string and print to the file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
perl -00ne 's|\s+$||; s# [\r\n]+ #|#xg; print $_, "\n";' input_file
```

- `-00` turns on `paragraph mode` where records from file are separated by **two** or more new lines.
- `s|\s+$||` removes any trailing white spaces, and `s# [\r\n]+ #|#xg` replaces remaining newlines with `|`

Replacement for one liner:

```
sub read_from_file {
    local $/ = "";
    open my $fh, "input_file" or die $!;
    while (<$fh>) {
      s|\s+$||;
      s# [\r\n]+ #|#xg;
      print $_, "\n";
    }
    close $fh;
}
```

Comment: @Soncire set `local $/ = "";` and put code in while loop which reads from file

Comment: here is my  code
while (my $line = <$input_fh>) {  
 chomp($line) unless($ClientFlag =~ /^Closingtot/i);  
 print $OUTPUTA $line."\n" if $line ne "";
}

Comment: Im sorry I dont understand  your instruction on how to do it

Answer (score 1):

```
while (<>) {
  chomp;
  if (/^{$/ .. /^(})$/) {
    if ($1 || /^$/) {
      print "$a\n";                                                             
      $a = ""; 
    } elsif (!/^{$/) {
      $a .= "|" if ($a == '');
      $a .= $_; 
    }   
  }
}
```

But mpapec's is quite a bit more elegant :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a script that suits your needs:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $line = '';
while(<DATA>) {
    if( /^\S/ ) {
        chomp;
        $line .= '|' if $line ne '';
        $line .= $_ 
    }
    else {
        print $line, "\n";
        $line = '';
    }
}
print $line, "\n" if($line);

__END__
Client1|fiswt|36214|784423|21 March 2013
Office|Level 9 83 Clarence Street
Transout|Cash|6904.29|$2.32|$16,000.00
closingtot|$236,313.84

Client1|fiswt|36214|784423|21 March 2013
Office|Level 9 83 Clarence Street
Transout|Cash|6904.29|$2.32|$16,000.00
closingtot|$236,313.84

Client1|fiswt|36214|784423|21 March 2013
Office|Level 9 83 Clarence Street
Transout|Cash|6904.29|$2.32|$16,000.00
closingtot|$236,313.84
```

Answer (score 0):

Read your data as paragraphs and replace the spaces with your field separator.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# --------------------------------------
# Modules

use English qw( -no_match_vars );

# --------------------------------------
#       Name: read_paragraph
#      Usage: $paragraph = read_paragraph( \*fh );
#    Purpose: Read the next paragraph from the file handle
# Parameters:       \*fh -- The file handle to read from
#    Returns: $paragraph -- the paragraph
#
sub read_paragraph {
  my $fh = shift @_;

  local $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR = "\n\n";
  my $paragraph = readline( $fh );

  return $paragraph;
}

# --------------------------------------
# Main

while( my $para = read_paragraph( \*DATA )){
  $para =~ s{ \s+ }{|}gmsx;
  $para =~ s{ (?> \| )+ \z }{}msx;
  print "$para\n";
}


__DATA__
Client1|fiswt|36214|784423|21 March 2013
Office|Level 9 83 Clarence Street
Transout|Cash|6904.29|$2.32|$16,000.00
closingtot|$236,313.84

Client1|fiswt|36214|784423|21 March 2013
Office|Level 9 83 Clarence Street
Transout|Cash|6904.29|$2.32|$16,000.00
closingtot|$236,313.84

Client1|fiswt|36214|784423|21 March 2013
Office|Level 9 83 Clarence Street
Transout|Cash|6904.29|$2.32|$16,000.00
closingtot|$236,313.84
```